# How do you load third party package in Codeigniter?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

This is elementary question.

I downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK and stored it in "third_party" folder within Codeigniter. I am hoping that is where it should go. But how do you load such PHP SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up sticking in in CI's libraries directory and adding it to the libraries autoload in config/autoload.php

autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('facebook');
```

Then, I made a small change to the Facebook implementation itself (constructor of the Facebook class) and added the keys to my app's config file:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $this->setAppId($ci->config->item('fb_appId'));
    $this->setApiSecret($ci->config->item('fb_secret'));
    $this->setCookieSupport($ci->config->item('fb_cookie'));
    $this->setBaseDomain($ci->config->item('fb_domain'));
    $this->setFileUploadSupport($ci->config->item('fb_upload'));
}
```

...And presto - you now have access to Facebook's API in your models and controllers via `$this->facebook`

Comment: Demian can you post the after login url? I implemented your suggestion and it is taking me to FB. After I enter my crendentials and authorize my app, I get redirected back to my app with the session Id and some other query strings. Can you show me how to handle those variables? where do I store them?